# Copy old Numix theme from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: xfce, numix

I just updated from Xubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 and it seems that someone played with the Numix theme making it more ugly.

1.The panel font color "white" is not "white" anymore, is some kind of "grey".
2.The "System load monitor" has a white background, instead of black one, like in 16.04, now it looks really horrible.
3.The start menu was dark, now it's a light grey.
4.The text for a a selected tab is red, instead of old normal black.

I have tried Oomox but I did more good than bad, therefore is there a method to just copy the entire theme from 16.04? Also, where can I put some bugs related to this, especially for the horrible white background of "Load Monitor"?

[image: panel 16.04]

[image: panel 18.04]

[image: load monitor 16.04]

[image: load monitor 18.04]

[image: tab selection]

Comment: While you can physically copy anything from one OS to another, themes are dependent on the gtk version which changed from 16.04 to 18.04. So copying over a gtk theme from 16.04 to 18.04 isn't advisable.

Comment: Re. feedback, you could raise an issue at https://github.com/numixproject/numix-gtk-theme